# how to find the text in SMTP .eml file from an SMS text message

Tags: asp.net, windows, email, smtp, sms

User sends a text message to my web site, my Windows 2012 server receives this as a .eml file in inetpub\mailroot\drop.

The file has lots of overhead besides the text.

What is the algorithm to find just the text that the user typed?

My app is a Visual Studio 2015 VB.NET application.

Comment: does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a library like [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) to parse the .eml messages.

You'll be able to parse the message like this:

```
var message = MimeMessage.Load ("inetpub\mailroot\drop\message.eml");
```

Once you have the parsed `MimeMessage`, you want to read the documentation at http://www.mimekit.org/docs/html/WorkingWithMessages.htm to understand how messages are structured.

Most likely, though, you'll be able to access the text of the message like this:

```
string text = message.TextBody;
```